# Expand div width when other div is not there

Tags: css, html, width, expand

I have a query. I am using 2divs in a main fixed width div.

i.e.

```
<div style="width:500px; border:red solid 1px; display:inline-block; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px">
    <div style="float:left; width:55%; border:green solid 1px;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec urna ipsum, lacinia ac fringilla in, porta at tellus. Integer euismod laoreet
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; padding:10px ">
        <select name="" style="width:200px; padding:4px ">
            <option>ABC</option>
            <option>XYZ</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

hidding div and td

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td:empty").css('display', 'none');
    $("div[class='errorMsg']").filter(function(i,v){return $.trim($(v).text()).length == 0;}).css('display', 'none');
    $("td[class='noShow']").filter(function(i,v){return $.trim($(v).text()).length == 0;}).css('display', 'none');
  });
```

I am trying to expand the content div when the drop down select div is not there. And when drop down select div is there it should come like this as its now.
I am able to this with table but i am stuck in div's.

if i use table-cell in css it doesnt work on ie7.

Comment: Which `div` *is* the 'content' `div`?

Comment: Are you hidding the div with dropdown or removing it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just setting the **display property of div with dropdown to None**. Then you can do something like this :

```
if($('#DIV_WITH_DROPDOWN').is(":visible")) {
    $('#CONTENT_DIV').css('width', WHATEVER VALUE YOU WANT);
}
```

**Remember it will only check for display:[none|block] and will ignores visible:[true|false]**

And if you are **removing the div completely or not loading the div in DOM** then you can use this:

```
if($('#DIV_WITH_DROPDOWN').length > 0) {
    $('#CONTENT_DIV').css('width', WHATEVER VALUE YOU WANT);
}
```

Comment: I am hiding the <div> and <td> like this. I am able to this when i use table. But i am not able to use it on div. If i hide select div by display:none. The content div doesn't expand. I have edited my code.How i am hiding the <div> and <td>. I want to do it for div. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: like what? can you plz give me the code you are using to hide the div so that I can give you according to you r situation.